# Client authentication (SSL) passthrough?

Tags: java, authentication, ssl

I have a web app that uses client authentication, that works.

My problem: the web app needs to interact with a 3rd party RESTful service. Kicker: that service requires client authentication using the same certificates the web app is using. Basically the web-app will be making those RESTful calls on behalf of the user logged into my web-app.

I don't think this is possible without having the private keys accessible in the web-app. Am I missing anything?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: You are correct. The web-app will have to have its own identity to the RESTFul application, its own certificate, keypair, etc.

Comment: Cool, figured. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score -1):

So your worry is exposing your app's security to a 3rd party service? 
I'm confused as to how the 3rd party service knows the certification is the same as the one your web app is generating for the user. Can you provide some more information about the 3rd party service? I've never seen a 3rd party service that would ask for the users information with regards to your app, but generally all parties generate a shared certificate through ouath or what not. 
It sounds like the app is hitting a public API, if the app is making all the requests on behalf of the users you just wrap your app's information into each request before hitting their service, so the user never really sees anything. I don't see the need to make them accessible to a user. Am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: The third party is the one that actually whitelists the certs. I'm just using them because they already exist. The third party doesn't care about the app, just the user. My business case is a web-app that adds value beyond what the third party service provides. The problem is to successfully open a HTTPS connection for client authentication I need each users private key...

Comment: Three questions, no answer. Should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: I'm new to stack, it didn't let me =/